# Initial approximation to inverse of beta distribution function / quantile of beta distribution

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, approximation

I'm interested in implementing an algorithm to find the quantile of the beta distribution, and I'm looking at this paper: [Journal of the Royal Statistical Society Series C (Applied Statistics). 1973, Vol. 22 Issue 3, p411. 4p, K. L. Majumder and G. P. Bhattacharjee](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2346798?uid=3738032&uid=2134&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21103992669357). The paper presents an algorithm, together with a FORTRAN implementation, to find $x$ satisfying

$$ I_x(p,q) = \frac1{B(p,q)}\int_0^xt^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1}\,\mathrm{d}t \;=\; \alpha$$

where the inputs are

- the quantile $\alpha \in [0,1]$;
- and the parameters of the Beta distribution $p,q>0$.

The algorithm comprises

1. Initial approximation, followed by
2. Newton-Raphson iteration.

(note that the algorithm has been refined by subsequent papers)

I'm interested in understanding the initial approximation a little better. The paper starts by quoting some results

[image]

> where $Y_\alpha$ is Hasting's approximation for the upper $100\alpha\%$ point of the standard normal distribution. If $\chi^2_\alpha < 0$, then

$$ x_0 = 1- [(1-\alpha)q\,B(p,q)]^{1/q}\;\;\;(\dagger)$$

> Again if $(4p+2q-2)/\chi^2_\alpha$ does not exceed $1$, $x_0$ is obtained from

$$ x_0 = [\alpha p \, B(p,q)]^{1/p}\;\;\;(\ddagger)$$

What I'm interested in is where do $(\dagger)$ and $(\ddagger)$ come from? Thanks for any help.